# Floating wrapped figure in a twocolumn page

Tags: floats, two-column, wrapfigure

I am creating a big composite book `\documentclass[A4,twocolumn]{book}`. I need wrapped floating figures (and tables) over both columns.

I know the enviroment `figure*`, but the full width of a page is so big. There are a lot of figures with small one-column overlaps - using `figure*` will result in an enormous increase in the number of pages.

Here [How to use wrapfig to span multiple columns](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/multiple-span.txt) I read about using [`wrapfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig/) to do it, but it isn't an easy way to do it.

Is there some another solution?

Example:

```
Lorem ipsum   Lorem ipsum
et dolorem    et dolorem
amenbat aqu   amenbat aqu
+-----------------+ Lorem 
|                 | ipsum
|      figure     | et dolo-
|                 | rem ame-
+-----------------+ bat Lo-
Lorem ipsum   rem ipsum 
et dolorem    et dolorem
```

Comment: AFAIK, `wrapfig` is the easiest.

Answer (score 2):

Only possible for one column

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{%%
\includegraphics[height=10\normalbaselineskip,
                 width=0.9\linewidth]{foo}}
\opencutleft

\begin{cutout}{4}{0pt}{0.3\linewidth}{11}
\lipsum[1]
\end{cutout}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]